# measurable finite-valued function

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading the measurable function in the book of stein's real analysis. It is stated that

> The finite-valued function $f$ is measurable if and only if $f^{-1}(O)$ is measurable for every open set $O$.

I am not sure whether the 'finite-valued' condition is necessary. Is there any counter example to verify this condition?

Comment: You have typed $f(0)$ for $f^{-1}(0)$

Comment: It is not, this is just a step in the way to defining a condition for measurability of general functions.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be a non-measurable set. If $f=\infty I_E  -\infty I_{E^{c}}$ then the inverse image of any open subset of $\mathbb R$ is empty, hence measurable. However $f$ is not measurable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your example, $f^{-1}((0,\infty))=\{x: f(x)>0\}=E$, and it is non-measurable.

Comment: It is not true that $f^{-1} ((0,\infty))=E$. If $x \in E$ then $f(x) =\infty \notin (0,\infty)$. @ZHANGWei

Comment: You mean that for a set $\{x: x>0 \}=(0,+\infty]$? I am kind of confusing about the notations, do you mean that $(0,\infty)$ and $(0,\infty]$ are not equivalent? @ Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: $f^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is, by definition, the set of points $x$ such that  $0<f(x) <\infty$. There are no such points for this function so $f^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is the empty set.

Comment: One more thing. We know that $(0, \infty)$ an open set. What is the case for $(0,\infty]$?  Is it an open set or not defined? If it is an open set, the statement will not hold. @Kavi Rama Murthy